# Bodies connected by a joint must be added to the same CCPhysicsNode, however two bodies are under the same CCPhysicsNode but

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I am making application by this tutorial.

https://www.makegameswith.us/tutorials/getting-started-with-spritebuilder/spritebuilder-physics/

I made jointnode directly in code like this

```
_mouseJoint = [CCPhysicsJoint connectedSpringJointWithBodyA:_mouseJointNode.physicsBody bodyB:_catapultArm.physicsBody anchorA:ccp(0, 0) anchorB:ccp(34, 138) restLength:0.f stiffness:3000.f damping:150.f];
```

but even though surely two nodes are under the same CCPhysicNode,

it shows this error

```
Bodies connected by a joint must be added to the same CCPhysicsNode,
```

Does anyone have same issue as this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: show a screenshot of your ccb node hierarchy, pretty sure you *do* have them in different physics nodes

Comment: I made new project to make the problem simple. However it shows the same problem, and I think two catapultarm and CCNode is under the same CCPhysicsNode. Am I correct?

Comment: that is correct. are you using ccphysicsnode in any other ccb file? Do both nodes have physics enabled? Perhaps the error is simply misleading and also occurs when one of the physicsbodies is nil.

Comment: My CCNode doesn't have physics enabled......

Comment: There's your problem. You can only connect joints with two nodes that have a physicsBody (aka physics enabled).

Comment: thanks probelm is sloved!!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, it turns out I had not enabled physics on the _mouseNode. Enabling physics on the node solved the problem.