# 'Bodies connected by a joint must be added to the same CCPhysicsNode.'-- but both nodes are added to same physics node

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I am following this link for getting started into Sprite Builder.

https://www.makegameswith.us/tutorials/getting-started-with-spritebuilder/spritebuilder-physics/

I made a joint like this :

```
    _penguinCatapultJoint = [CCPhysicsJoint connectedPivotJointWithBodyA:_currentPenguin.physicsBody bodyB:_catapultArm.physicsBody anchorA:_currentPenguin.anchorPointInPoints];
```

i got an error saying : "Bodies connected by a joint must be added to the same CCPhysicsNode"

I followed this link for solution: 
[Bodies connected by a joint must be added to the same CCPhysicsNode, however two bodies are under the same CCPhysicsNode but](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24364897/bodies-connected-by-a-joint-must-be-added-to-the-same-ccphysicsnode-however-two)

which says to enable physics property of both objects which i have done already and i am still getting the error:

'Bodies connected by a joint must be added to the same CCPhysicsNode.'

For convenience i am uploading images from spriteBuilder

[image: image showing _currentPenguin physics]

[image: image showing _currentPenguin variable name]

[image: image showing _catapultArm physics]

[image: image showing _catapultArm variable name]

Please help.

Comment: _currentPenguin and _catapultArm are non-nil?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D  they are not nil. The console gives me this 'current penguin : <CCSprite = 0xb0e7800 | Rect = (0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00) | tag =  >'  and 'catapult arm : <CCSprite = 0xb9aa400 | Rect = (61.00,961.50,42.00,177.50) | tag =  >'

Comment: @LearnCocos2D When i went through the tutorial closely i found they are allocating the _currentPenguin by code. There is no need of having  a CCNode for _currentPenguin in SpriteBuilder. So i removed that CCNode from SpriteBuilder and then started agin but encountered the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Check to which CCPhysicsNode you're adding the new penguin, ie:

```
// add it to the physics world
    [_physicsNode addChild:_currentPenguin];
```

In this case, it's added to `_physicsNode`.

Go back to `Gameplay.ccb` (in SpriteBuilder), and check that the `CCPhysicsNode` named `_physicsNode` (Doc root var), is the same where you added your `catapultarm`.